# Custom Field Type - create a custom address

Tags: list, custom-field-types

I follow the instruction from  [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg132913(v=office.14).aspx) to create a custom address field type.
I have 3 address: visiting, postal, and invoicing. So I based on the SPFieldMultiColumnValue to implement. Following is the class of CustomAddress

```
public class CustomAddress : SPFieldMultiColumn
    {
        public CustomAddress(SPFieldCollection fields,
                                   string fieldName)
            : base(fields, fieldName) { }

        public CustomAddress(SPFieldCollection fields,
                                   string typeName,
                                   string displayName)
            : base(fields, typeName, displayName) { }

        public override BaseFieldControl FieldRenderingControl
        {
            get
            {
                BaseFieldControl ctr = new AddressFieldControl();
                ctr.FieldName = this.InternalName;
                return ctr;
            }
        }

        public override string GetFieldValueAsHtml(object value)
        {
            string HtmlLineBreak = @"<br />";
            SPFieldMultiColumnValue mcv = new SPFieldMultiColumnValue(value.ToString());            
            string HtmlAddress = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < mcv.Count; i++)
            {
                HtmlAddress += mcv[i].ToString() + HtmlLineBreak;               
            }
            return HtmlAddress;
        }
    }
```

I set mvc[0] as Visting address, mvc[ 1] as postal address and mvc [2] as invoicing address. Everything works fine for creating and editing item. However, I have issue with viewing item (DisplayForm.aspx). It just shows the visiting address only. Look like it just get the mvc[0] and ignore mvc[ 1] and mvc[ 2]. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an implementation of fldtypes_whatever.xml? That is where I have the pattern for the DisplayForm.aspx and all the fields seem to show up ok. Should be somewhat appropriate: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toddca/archive/2009/01/23/customizing-the-rendering-of-a-custom-spfield.aspx